# I created tomcat filter in tomcat/conf/web.xml ,tomcat/lib .page content is not loading for the request.but filter executing

Tags: java, tomcat

I added just SOP statement in `dofilter` method. When I was trying to request the page, it goes into method but the page content is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a telepath, but you should call `chain.next()` in your filter.